# How can I calculate current with load switch?

Tags: current, current-measurement, load, current-sensor

I want to use a load switch for protecting my PCB.

I also want to watch/measure the current drawn by my board.

How can I sense/measure the current drawn by my board, using a load switch like the [Microchip UCS3205T-E/Q8A](https://www.digikey.be/product-detail/en/microchip-technology/UCS3205T-E-Q8A/150-UCS3205T-E-Q8ATR-ND/13415081)?

I can't find articles about sensing/measuring the load current.

Answer (score 1):

Load switch TPS272C45 by Texas Instruments outputs the current drawn by the load.

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps272c45.pdf?ts=1618175801421

---

SNS is an analog output pin that outputs the analog output current drawn by the load.

Connect a resistor between SNS and GND.

---

This a selection filter at Texas Instruments in case you want to browse other load switches:

https://www.ti.com/power-management/power-switches/high-side-switches/products.html